# PayPal IPN acknowledgements failing with SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure

Tags: ssl, paypal, paypal-ipn

With no changes on our side and perhaps related to POODLE/SSL3 our PayPal API call to PPIPNMessage::validate is now failing with.

```
SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure
```

The checkout and receipt of IPN is fine (and we have never supported SSL3 incoming), it's just failing when acknowledging the IPN (oddly PayPal doesn't try again, even though we have failed)

Running curl from the same server command line succeeds

```
$ curl -iv https://ipnpb.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr
* About to connect() to ipnpb.paypal.com port 443 (#0)
*   Trying 173.0.88.8... connected
* successfully set certificate verify locations:
*   CAfile: none
  CApath: /etc/ssl/certs
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server hello (2):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, CERT (11):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Server finished (14):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Client key exchange (16):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSLv3, TLS change cipher, Client hello (1):
* SSLv3, TLS handshake, Finished (20):
* SSL connection using AES256-SHA
* Server certificate:
*    subject: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.3=US; 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.60.2.1.2=Delaware; businessCategory=Private Organization; serialNumber=3014267; C=US; postalCode=95131-2021; ST=California; L=San Jose; street=2211 N 1st St; O=PayPal, Inc.; OU=PayPal Production; CN=ipnpb.paypa
*    start date: 2013-06-28 00:00:00 GMT
*    expire date: 2015-08-02 23:59:59 GMT
*    subjectAltName: ipnpb.paypal.com matched
*    issuer: C=US; O=VeriSign, Inc.; OU=VeriSign Trust Network; OU=Terms of use at https://www.verisign.com/rpa (c)06; CN=VeriSign Class 3 Extended Validation SSL CA
*    SSL certificate verify ok.
> GET /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.22.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.22.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1 zlib/1.2.3.4 libidn/1.23 librtmp/2.3
> Host: ipnpb.paypal.com
> Accept: */*
```

I did note that ssllabs.com shows 1 out of 4 IPs still supporting SSL3 on this endpoint.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is the same problem as [Error 0x1408F10B: "SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number" with PayPal SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378351/error1408f10bssl-routinesssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number-paypal-maybe)

The version of PayPal API we are using hard codes CURLOPT_SSLVERSION to 3.

Our fix is to insert this before any PayPal calls.

```
PPHttpConfig::$DEFAULT_CURL_OPTS[CURLOPT_SSLVERSION] = 4;
```

Comment: yes, our IPNs are now being validated. I see that SSLv3 has been removed from sandbox endpoints overnight and most of the live IPN reply endpoints. I have to think it can't be long before it's removed from the main api-3t.paypal.com endpoint too - at which point all SSLv3 calls to PayPal will fail.

Comment: Yes thank you Paypal for the advanced notice. Live site went down and lost hours of time searching for a solution. Very unhappy. Fix works for me.

Comment: Hm, I'm using standard cURL, when I set curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4); it still not working. Any ideas?

Comment: Well, the PHP documentation says that a value of 1 means TLSv1.0. It doesn't define a meaning for 4 - http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php

Comment: The `4`, `5`, and `6` values are for cURL 7.34+, so some older PHP versions won't work with those values. I used value `1` and it worked wonderfully on my semi-outdated version of PHP. :)

Answer (score 15):

I had the same problem... Just change the following line on the **ipnlistener.php**

from:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 3);
```

to:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
```

**ipnlistener.php**

```
<?php
/**
* PayPal IPN Listener
*
* A class to listen for and handle Instant Payment Notifications (IPN) from
* the PayPal server.
*
* https://github.com/Quixotix/PHP-PayPal-IPN
*
* @package PHP-PayPal-IPN
* @author Micah Carrick
* @copyright (c) 2012 - Micah Carrick
* @version 2.1.0
*/
class IpnListener {

    /**
* If true, the recommended cURL PHP library is used to send the post back
* to PayPal. If flase then fsockopen() is used. Default true.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_curl = true;

    /**
* If true, explicitly sets cURL to use SSL version 3. Use this if cURL
* is compiled with GnuTLS SSL.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $force_ssl_v3 = true;

    /**
* If true, cURL will use the CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION to follow any
* "Location: ..." headers in the response.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $follow_location = false;

    /**
* If true, an SSL secure connection (port 443) is used for the post back
* as recommended by PayPal. If false, a standard HTTP (port 80) connection
* is used. Default true.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_ssl = true;

    /**
* If true, the paypal sandbox URI www.sandbox.paypal.com is used for the
* post back. If false, the live URI www.paypal.com is used. Default false.
*
* @var boolean
*/
    public $use_sandbox = false;

    /**
* The amount of time, in seconds, to wait for the PayPal server to respond
* before timing out. Default 30 seconds.
*
* @var int
*/
    public $timeout = 30;

    private $post_data = array();
    private $post_uri = '';
    private $response_status = '';
    private $response = '';

    const PAYPAL_HOST = 'www.paypal.com';
    const SANDBOX_HOST = 'www.sandbox.paypal.com';

    /**
* Post Back Using cURL
*
* Sends the post back to PayPal using the cURL library. Called by
* the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is true. Throws an
* exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
* and post_uri properties on success.
*
* @param string The post data as a URL encoded string
*/
    protected function curlPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'https://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        } else {
            $uri = 'http://'.$this->getPaypalHost().'/cgi-bin/webscr';
            $this->post_uri = $uri;
        }

        $ch = curl_init();

                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, true);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CAINFO,
                 dirname(__FILE__)."/cert/api_cert_chain.crt");
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $uri);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $encoded_data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, $this->follow_location);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, $this->timeout);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);

        if ($this->force_ssl_v3) {
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4); //Modified from 3 to 4
        }

        $this->response = curl_exec($ch);
        $this->response_status = strval(curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE));

        if ($this->response === false || $this->response_status == '0') {
            $errno = curl_errno($ch);
            $errstr = curl_error($ch);
            throw new Exception("cURL error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }
    }

    /**
* Post Back Using fsockopen()
*
* Sends the post back to PayPal using the fsockopen() function. Called by
* the processIpn() method if the use_curl property is false. Throws an
* exception if the post fails. Populates the response, response_status,
* and post_uri properties on success.
*
* @param string The post data as a URL encoded string
*/
    protected function fsockPost($encoded_data) {

        if ($this->use_ssl) {
            $uri = 'ssl://'.$this->getPaypalHost();
            $port = '443';
            $this->post_uri = $uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        } else {
            $uri = $this->getPaypalHost(); // no "http://" in call to fsockopen()
            $port = '80';
            $this->post_uri = 'http://'.$uri.'/cgi-bin/webscr';
        }

        $fp = fsockopen($uri, $port, $errno, $errstr, $this->timeout);

        if (!$fp) {
            // fsockopen error
            throw new Exception("fsockopen error: [$errno] $errstr");
        }

        $header = "POST /cgi-bin/webscr HTTP/1.1\r\n";
        $header .= "Host: ".$this->getPaypalHost()."\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n";
        $header .= "Content-Length: ".strlen($encoded_data)."\r\n";
        $header .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";

        fputs($fp, $header.$encoded_data."\r\n\r\n");

        while(!feof($fp)) {
            if (empty($this->response)) {
                // extract HTTP status from first line
                $this->response .= $status = fgets($fp, 1024);
                $this->response_status = trim(substr($status, 9, 4));
            } else {
                $this->response .= fgets($fp, 1024);
            }
        }

        fclose($fp);
    }

    private function getPaypalHost() {
        if ($this->use_sandbox) return self::SANDBOX_HOST;
        else return self::PAYPAL_HOST;
    }

    /**
* Get POST URI
*
* Returns the URI that was used to send the post back to PayPal. This can
* be useful for troubleshooting connection problems. The default URI
* would be "ssl://www.sandbox.paypal.com:443/cgi-bin/webscr"
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getPostUri() {
        return $this->post_uri;
    }

    /**
* Get Response
*
* Returns the entire response from PayPal as a string including all the
* HTTP headers.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getResponse() {
        return $this->response;
    }

    /**
* Get Response Status
*
* Returns the HTTP response status code from PayPal. This should be "200"
* if the post back was successful.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getResponseStatus() {
        return $this->response_status;
    }

    /**
* Get Text Report
*
* Returns a report of the IPN transaction in plain text format. This is
* useful in emails to order processors and system administrators. Override
* this method in your own class to customize the report.
*
* @return string
*/
    public function getTextReport() {

        $r = '';

        // date and POST url
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n[".date('m/d/Y g:i A').'] - '.$this->getPostUri();
        if ($this->use_curl) $r .= " (curl)\n";
        else $r .= " (fsockopen)\n";

        // HTTP Response
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n{$this->getResponse()}\n";

        // POST vars
        for ($i=0; $i<80; $i++) { $r .= '-'; }
        $r .= "\n";

        foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
            $r .= str_pad($key, 25)."$value\n";
        }
        $r .= "\n\n";

        return $r;
    }

    /**
* Process IPN
*
* Handles the IPN post back to PayPal and parsing the response. Call this
* method from your IPN listener script. Returns true if the response came
* back as "VERIFIED", false if the response came back "INVALID", and
* throws an exception if there is an error.
*
* @param array
*
* @return boolean
*/
    public function processIpn($post_data=null) {

        $encoded_data = 'cmd=_notify-validate';

        if ($post_data === null) {
            // use raw POST data
            if (!empty($_POST)) {
                $this->post_data = $_POST;
                $encoded_data .= '&'.file_get_contents('php://input');
            } else {
                throw new Exception("No POST data found.");
            }
        } else {
            // use provided data array
            $this->post_data = $post_data;

            foreach ($this->post_data as $key => $value) {
                $encoded_data .= "&$key=".urlencode($value);
            }
        }

        if ($this->use_curl) $this->curlPost($encoded_data);
        else $this->fsockPost($encoded_data);

        if (strpos($this->response_status, '200') === false) {
            throw new Exception("Invalid response status: ".$this->response_status);
        }

        if (strpos($this->response, "VERIFIED") !== false) {
            return true;
        } elseif (strpos($this->response, "INVALID") !== false) {
            return false;
        } else {
            throw new Exception("Unexpected response from PayPal.");
        }
    }

    /**
* Require Post Method
*
* Throws an exception and sets a HTTP 405 response header if the request
* method was not POST.
*/
    public function requirePostMethod() {
        // require POST requests
        if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] && $_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST') {
            header('Allow: POST', true, 405);
            throw new Exception("Invalid HTTP request method.");
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: We're using the same library, but it is not working on my site. I even don't receive IPN request now. Any ideas?

Comment: Forcing cURL to use 4 is easy and proper way to fix the issue! Working like a charm!

Answer (score 13):

PayPal disabled SSLv3 in response to the "POODLE" vunerability. Read about it here: [PayPal Response](https://devblog.paypal.com/poodle-ssl-3-0-vulnerability/)

If you are using ipnlistener.php, force TLS 1.2 as the SSL Protocol:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2);
```

*(Updated: TLS V1.2 required for 2017)*

*Note:* PayPal is upgrading the protocols used to secure all external connections made to their systems. Transport Layer Security version 1.2 (TLS 1.2) and Hypertext Transfer Protocol version 1.1 (HTTP/1.1) will become mandatory for communication with PayPal in 2018. See their [Security Roadmap](https://www.paypal.com/webapps/mpp/tls-http-upgrade)

Answer (score 2):

SSLv3 is no more available for www.paypal.com:

```
# sslscan www.paypal.com|grep Accepted
Accepted  TLSv1  256 bits  AES256-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  AES128-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  168 bits  DES-CBC3-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-SHA
Accepted  TLSv1  128 bits  RC4-MD5
```

You should change your **CURLOPT_SSLVERSION** to **TLSv1**:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1);
```

(This "CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1"-constant is not available for older PHP Versions, so another way is to remove simply the CURLOPT_SSLVERSION enforcement.)

Answer (score 1):

For Me None of these things mentioned in the other answers worked but, I was able to figure out the fix and it's along the same lines, but took me a while to find out what file the sdk I was using put its curl config as there was no ipn listener file and that "PPHttpConfig" would give me a fatal error

so I found this is the listener file they are using now:

> PayPal-PHP-SDK/paypal/rest-api-sdk-php/lib/PayPal/Core/PayPalHttpConfig.php

I found inside

> CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 1

I changed it to:

> CURLOPT_SSLVERSION => 4

and that fixed it for me.

Comment: Kudos for the find @Kit Ramos, below are all the possible values as of April, 2016:

CURL_SSLVERSION_DEFAULT (0)
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1 (1)
CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv2 (2)
CURL_SSLVERSION_SSLv3 (3)
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_0 (4)
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_1 (5)
CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1_2 (6)

Answer (score 0):

I second that.
Lost *hours* trying to figure it out.
On my IPN listener I had to remove 'force ssl v3'.
From that moment on my IPN start working again.

Just do a 
    curl -v https://paypal.com

It shows:
    SSL connection using TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA

Answer (score 0):

I have same error while check IPN with PayPal. Here is the solutions of issue

I was worked with PHP 5.3 and PHP 5.3 is no longer support for SSL version 3. I have upgrade with PHP version with 5.4 and added below line of code. It's work for me.

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
#curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 4);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, CURL_SSLVERSION_TLSv1); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_CIPHER_LIST, 'TLSv1');
```

Answer (score -2):

Use this setting in your paypal class on calling function PPHttpPost()

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6); //6 is for TLSV1.2
```

Comment: This is NEVER a recommended setting in production environments. Those settings were meant to be TRUE to make sure no third party in the middle fakes the host you are connecting to.