# PayPal IPN stopped working - curl 35 error

Tags: php, paypal-ipn

I am using PayPal IPN to ping a PHP listener on my website. It has been working fine for over a year now until today. PayPal is showing the IPN was sent successfully, however if I look at my records it shows it was not processed from my end and if I look in the error log I can see the following error:

`[16-Oct-2014 10:54:41] cURL error: [35] error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure`

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this might happen? What can I do to fix it?

Comment: Have a read of http://unitstep.net/blog/2009/05/05/using-curl-in-php-to-access-https-ssltls-protected-sites/

Comment: these answers should help you out.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26379773/paypal-ipn-acknowledgements-failing-with-ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-aler

Comment: SOVLED! Turns out that PayPal disabled SSL3 support for the IPN scripts. The code I was using had force SSL enabled. I just disabled that and it works again.

Comment: Thank you for this!  Paypal, what a bunch of clowns.  How many sites broke because of this I wonder? Ugh.

Answer (score 10):

PayPal disabled SSLv3 as a response to the POODLE vunerability. You can read about it here: [PayPal Response](https://www.paypal.com/uk/webapps/mpp/ssl-security-update)