# Paypal error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)

Tags: paypal, sslv3

Hello i'm using paypal class in my e-commerce but when i put the code in my serverhost the paypal show me the mensage: 
SetExpressCheckout failed: error:14094410:SSL routines:SSL3_READ_BYTES:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)

this is my class:

```
class MyPayPal {    
function PPHttpPost($methodName_, $nvpStr_, $PayPalApiUsername, $PayPalApiPassword, $PayPalApiSignature, $PayPalMode) {
        // Set up your API credentials, PayPal end point, and API version.
        $API_UserName = urlencode($PayPalApiUsername);
        $API_Password = urlencode($PayPalApiPassword);
        $API_Signature = urlencode($PayPalApiSignature);

        $paypalmode = ($PayPalMode=='sandbox') ? '.sandbox' : '';

        $API_Endpoint = "https://api-3t".$paypalmode.".paypal.com/nvp";
        $version = urlencode('109.0');

        // Set the curl parameters.
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $API_Endpoint);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);

        // Turn off the server and peer verification (TrustManager Concept).
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, FALSE);

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

        // Set the API operation, version, and API signature in the request.
        $nvpreq = "METHOD=$methodName_&VERSION=$version&PWD=$API_Password&USER=$API_UserName&SIGNATURE=$API_Signature$nvpStr_";

        // Set the request as a POST FIELD for curl.
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $nvpreq);

        // Get response from the server.
        $httpResponse = curl_exec($ch);

        if(!$httpResponse) {
            exit("$methodName_ failed: ".curl_error($ch).'('.curl_errno($ch).')');
        }

        // Extract the response details.
        $httpResponseAr = explode("&", $httpResponse);

        $httpParsedResponseAr = array();
        foreach ($httpResponseAr as $i => $value) {
            $tmpAr = explode("=", $value);
            if(sizeof($tmpAr) > 1) {
                $httpParsedResponseAr[$tmpAr[0]] = $tmpAr[1];
            }
        }

        if((0 == sizeof($httpParsedResponseAr)) || !array_key_exists('ACK', $httpParsedResponseAr)) {
            exit("Invalid HTTP Response for POST request($nvpreq) to $API_Endpoint.");
        }

    return $httpParsedResponseAr;
 }

}
```

Any idea how can i solve this problem?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: read this link https://www.paypal-community.com/t5/PayPal-Forward/PayPal-Response-to-SSL-3-0-Vulnerability-aka-POODLE/ba-p/891829 hope it's helpful

Comment: Thanks, but not solve my problem .

Comment: have a look at these links
1) http://stackoverflow.com/a/26380523/3818903 
2) http://serverfault.com/questions/229972/error14094410ssl-routinesssl3-read-bytessslv3-alert-handshake-failure35