# PDO connection with SSL returning "SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number"

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, openssl, rackspace-cloud

I am attempting to connect to a Rackspace Cloud MySQL database with PDO and SSL. My connection string is:

```
$dbh = new PDO($serverAddress, $username, $password, array(
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY => true,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CA =>'rackspace.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_KEY => 'key.pem',
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_SSL_CERT => 'cert.pem'
 ));
```

This errors out with the message "PDO::__construct(): SSL operation failed with code 1. OpenSSL Error messages:
error:1408F10B:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number"

`rackspace.pem` is the Rackspace CA file provided [here](https://support.rackspace.com/how-to/using-ssl-with-your-cloud-database-instance/). `key.pem` and `cert.pem` are self-signed certificates (with the same FQDN as `rackspace.pem`). This connection works successfully without SSL.

I have enabled SSLv3 in the Apache configuration of my server (not sure if that is relevant here, as it is a PDO-calling-openssl issue).

I am able to connect to the DB instance via the mysql client. There, I see that the SSL version is TLSv1 (wondering if that is part of the issue, somehow?).

[image: Database SSL Version]

The things I have read about this error message (some examples - [Error 0x1408F10B: “SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number” with PayPal SDK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378351/error-0x1408f10b-ssl3-get-recordwrong-version-number-with-paypal-sdk), [how to solve SSL3_GET_RECORD:wrong version number error?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/git-users/5cQ4I7qRx0I)) are not relevant to the PDO library.

Any help or direction would be much appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: What do you get when you run `openssl version` on your server? You should know that SSL v3 is generally considered insecure now, and you should be using TLS: http://disablessl3.com

Comment: That error may mean that you're connecting to a non-SSL-aware socket. Do you need to set the port? Showing us a scrubbed version of your command line will help diagnose.

Comment: @JeremyHarris - I originally had SSLv3 disabled but re-enabled it to see if fixed the error. `openssl version` returns `OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016`

Comment: @bishop - `$serverAddress` above is `mysql:host=serverstingwhatever.rackspaceclouddb.com;port=3306;`. I was under the impression that SSL works over 3306.

Comment: SSL does work over 3306, as MySQL negotiates the transport. However, it also means that non-SSL aware clients can connect and that may not be desired. Thus, some installations have separate ports. Rackspace may be such an installation: show us your scrubbed command line.

Comment: Notwithstanding, try setting the full path to your certificates, instead of relative. Additionally, if your PHP installation uses `mysqlnd`, then set `pdo_mysql.debug = On` in your `php.ini`.

Comment: @bishop When I connect via command line with `mysql -h serverstring.rackspaceclouddb.com -u username -pPassword` and run `status`, I am shown that I am connected with SSL - `SSL:   Cipher in use is DHE-RSA-AES256-SHA`

I have tried full paths to certificates. I will check the `pdo_mysql.debug` setting and see what that returns.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130815/discussion-between-ryantkelly-and-bishop).

Comment: We probably need to see the client's `ClientHello` and the server's response. What protocols and ciphers is the client using? What is `$serverAddress`?